# How can I send selected date from datepicker to a controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

how can I use this piece of jquery code to grab the date from a datePicker when the user selects a date, then send the date as a string to the controller using BeginForm()? How do I access the code between the  tags to use with my razor and asp.net code?

Here’s what I’ve tried from following some tips on the forum but with no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        onSelect: Function(dateText, inst); 
        {
            var theDate = $("#date").datepicker('getDate');
            var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        }

     String selectedDate"";
    selectedDate=theDate.toString();


         });
```

So after the suggestions I’ve been trying to do this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {      
                $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd'})
        });  
        </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller",  new { @id = "formName", @Name = "formName" }))
{
 Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" onchange="$('#formName').submit();"
 }
```

Then in the controller:

```
public ActionResult myMethod(DateTime?  date=null)
{
if if (date != null)
            { 
            //do 
            }
}
```

In the controller, date is always null.  Am I naming my GeginForm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can populate an alternate field with its own date format whenever a date is selected using the `altField` and `altFormat` options. This feature could be used to present a human-friendly date for user selection, while passing a more computer-friendly date through for further processing.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Populate alternate field</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            altField: "#alternate",
            altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />&nbsp;<input type="text" id="alternate" size="30" /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfectly.   However when I check my formCollection in the controller, I don't see the selected date as one of the fields.  Can I somehow send the selected date using BiginForm() or some other means?  Thanks again for helping1

Answer (score 0):

You have over complicated things. simply you can use onchange event for the input and when the datepicker makes a change it will fire the action.

Controller:

```
          // You can use "String?" type here
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date = null)
{
    if (date != null)
    {
        // Your Logic Here!
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd' });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" onchange="$('#YourForm').submit();" />
```

I also use this for showing datas in that date whenever a date chosen by user. 
Easy and fast..

Comment: Which property of BigenForm can I use for '#YourForm'?

Comment: with `#YourForm` i meant `Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "YourForm" });` the actual id of your form. As an example: `Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "gman" });` and use the input as `<input type="text" class="datepicker" onchange="$('#gman').submit();" />` simple as this.